# Random selection from sub array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I need to select a random item (img1, img2, etc.) from simple nested arrays. I'm sure this is easy but I am stumped. The array has this format:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [homepage_image] => img1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [homepage_image] => img2
        )

)
```

$fields is the name of the main array.
I've tried using:

```
$random = array_rand($fields);
```

But of course that just gives me 0 or 1. How do I randomly get img1, img2, etc?

Comment: `$fields[array_rand($fields)]['homepage_image'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_rand()` to find a random key of your array:

```
$image = $fields[array_rand($fields)]['homepage_image'];
```

Comment: 14k, you should know not to post code-only answers.